# How to change the json structure created by Gson in java

Tags: java, json, gson, realm, realm-list

json created by Gson of List of Objects looks like.

```
"[[{"id":1,"name":"Shepherd"}],[{"id":2,"name":"Bull"}]]"
```

But I want this to be look like

```
"[{'id':1,'name':'Shepherd'},{'id':2,'name':'Bull'}]"
```

I created this json by using Gson library like this.

```
class Dog{
long id;
String name;
}

ArrayList<Dog> myDogs= new ArrayList<Dog>();
ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
objects = Application.getApplication.query(Object.class, " from Dog", 0, 0);
//Fetching data through HQL
myDogs=(ArrayList<Dog>)objects;
String jsonStr = new Gson().toJson(myDogs);
```

I want this specific structured json so that it directly converts to RealmList of Dog type by using.

```
 realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(Dog.class, jsonStr);
```

Comment: Gson would create the second list, so there must be something going wrong in your code which you did not show. Add the code of `(some initialization)`.

Comment: Ok. let me edit my post

Comment: Thanks for your time wero. The issue was exactly what ice told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting from your `query` is something like `List<List<Dog>>`
You need `List<Dog>` to obtain JSON as you want, try this variant

```
ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
objects = Application.getApplication.query(Object.class, " from Dog", 0, 0);
//Fetching data through HQL
myDogs=(ArrayList<List<Dog>)objects;
String jsonStr = new Gson().toJson(Iterables.concat(myDogs));
```

see http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat(java.lang.Iterable)

Comment: This is was the perfect answer of my question. Thanks